# Has anyone used the isomorphism with $\Bbb{N}_{\gt 0}$ as a monomial ordering?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, order-theory, groebner-generators

Let $R[x_1, x_2, \dots]$ be a ring of formal polynomials in a countably $\infty$ number of indeterminates $x_i$, over a commutative ring $R$.

The commutative monoid $X = \{ x^e = x_1^{e_1} x_2^{e_2} \cdots \vert e_i \in \Bbb{N}, \  e_i \neq 0 \text{ only finitely many times }\}$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{N}_{\gt 0}, \cdot)$.  An ismorphism is given by any bijection between $\{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$ and the primes $\{p_1, p_2, \dots \} \subset \Bbb{N}_{\gt 0}$ extended homomorphically.  Stated another way, any commutative free monoid on a countably $\infty$ set is isomorphic to $\Bbb{N}_{\gt 0}$.

So let $f: X \to \Bbb{N}_{\gt 0}$ be any such isomorphism.  Then the order on $X$ defined as $a \lt b \iff f(a) \lt f(b)$ is an admissible ordering (one that can be used for Gröbner bases).

Additionally, since $X$ is countable we have that $R[x_1, \dots]$ is an $R$-module with countable basis $X$.

Comment: Probably not. There are lots of such suitable orderings, and it seems unnecessary to try this one. Why do you think it might be interesting, compared to any other possible ordering?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews because it has a simple definition, uses the simple isomorphism to $\Bbb{N}_{\gt 0}$.  It seems equally arbitrary for the researchers to use the lex, degrevlex, etc, just because the 1-variable monomials are sometimes ordered that way.

Comment: The ones that are used are quite non-abitrary, really! In fact, they usual orders have very good properties in several ways.

Comment: it's not clear to me how you would "use" a monomial ordering for infinitely many variable to figure out the basis for an ideal, when the ideal could also be infinitely generated. As far as I know, the only reason to use the specific ordering is to compute an actual basis, so I'm not sure where you'd use this. You could certainly use it for finite polynomial rings, but the primes are so irregular, the order of $x_1^n$ and $x_2^m$ (assuming $x_1\mapsto 2$ and $x_2\mapsto 3$) is fairly complicated compared to lexical order.

Comment: In any case, you are doing it backwards. Usually the way to proceed is to have a concrete problem and then comee up with an orderin wich helps with it, and you seem to be looking for problems solvable by a (rather weird) order.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I am working on such problems, this is related.

Comment: But way too many questions you ask here are of the form, "this is a case of $X$. Is that interesting?" If you have a motivating example, tell, don't ask. There is huge amounts of literature out there; before you ask people to dig into them, give *motivation* for digging. Otherwise you get a lot of unanswered questions.

Comment: In particular, "$X$ is a $Y$, is that interesting?" is not really a useful mathematical question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think finite "Dirichlet sums" are isomorphic to the polynomials ring $\Bbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \dots]$.  If this order can be mapped on to the Dirichlet sums, then it becomes *the most* natural.  Since then $n^{-X} \lt (n+1)^{-X}$.

Comment: Here he is not asking if the order is interesting - he's asking if it's been used before, which I think is a valid use of Math.SE.